# Can I use PowerShell scripts in SharePoint 2013 somewhere in the Web GUI or from a client PC?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to run PowerShell scripts in SharePoint 2013 from the Web GUI or from a Client PC?

Example: I'd like to copy custom views from a document library in one site to another one in the same site collection.
This does not seem possible directly in the web GUI, so I found a PowerShell script which could do that:
http://rogierdijkman.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/copy-views-to-other-libraries-with-powershell/

I wonder how I can launch this script. 
I tried to execute it on my own computer (only a client to sharepoint) in Windows 7 with Windows 7 PowerShell ISE and it fails stating that the Windows PowerShell-Snap-Ins were not found.
I tried to find out how to install the SnapIns, but did not find a way.

So I wonder:

- do I have to have access to the Windows GUI of the servers to execute such a script?
- or can I also execute it from a client PC?
- which permissions do I need to execute such scripts from a client?
- Is there a way to directly launch PowerShell scripts from the SharePoint Central Administration web GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell remoting for PSRemoting allows you to do just the same. You need to activate it on the server end and configure which hosts are trusted.

Check this link out
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx